Interpreting matrix multiplication $A^TA$ as a linear operator
Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb k)$ be a matrix and $A^T$ be its transpose. With a basis chosen, every matrix like $A$ in $M_n(\mathbb k)$ corresponds to a linear operator $\varphi_A\in\text{End}(V)$ where $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb k$ with dimension $n$. Let $[\varphi]$ be the matrix corresponding to $\varphi$ under the basis chosen. In this way, there is homomorphism
$$
\varphi_A\circ\varphi_B=\varphi_{A\cdot B}
$$
For any such $\varphi_A:V\longrightarrow V$, I know that there is a dual operator $\varphi_A^T:V^*\longrightarrow V^*$ where $V^*=\text{Hom}_{\mathsf{Vect}(\mathbb k)}(V,\mathbb k)$ is the dual space of $V$. If $V$ and $V^*$ both have standard basis chosen, we have
$$
[\varphi_A^T]=[\varphi_{A}]^T=A^T
$$
Consider matrix multiplication $B=A^TA$. By the homomorphism, we should have
$$
\varphi_B=\varphi_{A^T}\circ \varphi_A=\varphi_{[\varphi_A^T]}\circ\varphi_A
$$
Here $\varphi_B,\varphi_A\in\mathcal L(V,V)$, so that $\varphi_{[\varphi_A^T]}\in\mathcal L(V,V)$. My question is that how can we construct two maps $f:V\longrightarrow V^*$ and $g:V^*\longrightarrow V$ such that
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
V @>{f}>> V^*\\
@V{\varphi_{[\varphi_A^T]}}VV @VV{\varphi_A^T}V \\
V @<<{g}< V^*
\end{CD}
$$
Is commutative? If so, such $f$ and $g$ "unique up to isomorphism"?

It's a nice question but I don't think it has an answer with so little structure. You need to introduce a scalar product. This way, there will be no dual space anymore and you can meaningfully compose A and A^t. Indeed, things such as A^tA only appear in the context of Hilbert spaces, that is, spaces with scalar products.

As Giuseppe says, you need to introduce an inner product. $f$ and $g$ are given by currying that inner product, which turns the dual operator into the adjoint operator.
